# How to not register global commands to my bot's test server?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been developing my Discord bot in a test server where I deploy all the commands locally to only that server. However, I finished developing my bot today, and so I deployed all my commands globally to test them in other servers and everything works great...

Except now in my test server I have two copies of every command?? One local copy and one global copy...

I would like to keep only the local versions in the test server, because the global version take up to one hour to update, which is not convenient for quick testing.

As an example, this is what I see when I try to run the `/ping` command to my bot:
[image: An image illustrating the problem]

Is there a way to not register the global commands to my test server? Or at least some way to mark which commands are the local (updated) ones and which ones are the global (outdated) ones? This has been a huge pain for testing and I have to think there's some way to get rid of it...

Comment: You could probably put `(local)` or `(global)` in the description

Comment: @MrMythical Thanks. I thought of that, but I can't do that because they're both deployed from the same file, so changing the description of one will change it for both... Thanks for the tip though!